# Find $\arg(z),$ if $|z|=|z-|z||$ and $z$ - non-zero number

Tags: complex-numbers

$z$ - non-zero number. I need to find the argument $z,$ when $|z|=|z-|z||.$ I'm literally stopped. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = re^{i\theta}, r>0 \Rightarrow |z| =r$

So,

$\begin{align}&r = |re^{i\theta}- r| = r|e^{i\theta} - 1| \\\Rightarrow &1 = |e^{i\theta} - 1| = \sqrt{(\cos\theta -1)^2 + \sin^2\theta} = 2\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|\\\Rightarrow& 1 = 2\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|\end{align}$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the Argand-Cauchy plane $\:Oxy\:$ and let $M$ be the affix of $z$ and $A$ be the point on the real axis with abscissa $|z|$. Observe that $\bigl|z-|z|\bigr|$ is the length of $\:\overrightarrow{\!AM}$. What can you deduce for triangle $OAM$?